# Python/Flask - Interal REST-API or specific url handling

Tags: python, api, rest, flask

At the moment I write a bookmarking application for learning purposes in Python with Flask and work with those bookmarks and its metadata to edit, delete, show statistics etc. Imagine I have a template where I can create a bookmark at the top via **POST** request and a table with all bookmarks below, where you can delete a specific one with a **DELETE** request.

Should I build an internal *restful api* to do this instead of handling this by the type of request in the same template?

It could be possible that I use the same data for graphs at a different location in the application. At least it looks and sounds *restful*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you really want to just do simple jobs like (editing , deleting ,...) it doesn't matter what way you choose but personally in this situation I prefer to handle it myself , if not and you will create new jobs and your system will become complex it's better to create your own restful api .
cause you just create this application for educational purposes I think it is better to use RESTFUL API and become familiar with it , you can start from here http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I also want to implement a select field with an autocomplete function for existing tags as suggestion. A JS/jQuery script would fetch the matching tag names in realtime. What would in this case make more sense?

Comment: Another scenario would be, that I list all bookmarks in a table, but only want to delete a specific one.

Comment: @user3147268 In both scenario you could handle them without restful easily but it is not the only way.

Answer (score 0):

A restful api sounds like the best approach. Plus it will give you the possibility to further improve or extend the system if at some point you need to query or present the data in a richer way, like plotting or any other kind of visualization or even share it with other people.

There are many options there, and flask-restful offers a great flexibility. Based on this I recommend a framework that I've been working on called Peach(https://github.com/sebastiandev/peach) which is built on top of flask-restful and really speeds things up, allowing you to have a api running in a few minutes. I commend it no only because i built it, but because if was born out of the necessity of a lightweight option to django and other frameworks, flexible enough to adapt it to my needs that would let me built prototypes and simple apps in a breeze.

There are examples and even a virtual machine to test them. Happy coding :)